# Executemany gives "TypeError: not enough arguments for format string"

Tags: python, mysql, database, typeerror, executemany

I'm trying to insert many rows in MySQL database and for some reason I'm always getting this error.
I have already tried the solutions present in this topic and nothing works.

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

My Code:

```
cursor = db.cursor()

        row = (date, timetoserve, ipcliente, cacheCode, bytesint, method,\
        url.scheme, url.hostname, url.port, url.path, auth, route[0], route[1], contentType)

        items.append(row)

        if Inputs % 100 == 0:
                sql = "INSERT INTO LogTbl \
                (DateConnection, TimeToServe, ClientIP, CacheCode, Bytes, Method,\
                RequestProtocol, RequestIP, RequestPort, RequestFolder, Auth, RouteLeft, RouteRight, ContentType)\
                VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"

            cursor.executemany(sql, items)
            items = []
            db.commit()
```

Comment: If you print (sql) does it look right?  The error makes it sound like there is a miscount between the number of %s and elements in row.

Comment: Yes, it prints the SQL code, without "\" but it has more spaces on the "\"

Comment: If you copy/paste that SQL into your management tool (sql workbench or whatever) it runs OK?

Comment: I get errors on the "%s"

Comment: If i change the "%s" to "?" the error is different "_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during string formatting" I also searched this error and nothing worked

Comment: maybe try to get this to work for simply 1 item (just 1 row) with %s, if you can get that to work then try doing it with executemany

Comment: I have one script with this working but only sending one line each time, and I have like, 700000 lines to send and we cant wait that many time so I have to send multiple lines. the script is similar. cursor.execute("INSERT INTO LogTbl (all the fields) VALUES (all the %s)", (all the variables)) (the variables are the same as the row =(...))

Comment: OK, sounds like you are doing everything right. Hm.  executemany is certainly the right way to go with this.  I wonder if the SQL string it too long and getting truncated.  Try it with maybe only 10 items?

Comment: nop, exactly the same error... I dont know if its possible to print the executemany but it gives me some white spaces in the terminal

Comment: I have a little sample example that is working for me, do you see anything different?  I'm using ? instead of %s but you already tried that http://collabedit.com/4db3q